# Prometheus Mysql Exporter: Error pinging mysqld

Tags: prometheus

Configured Prometheus Mysql Exporter according to the instructions. Everything started, but there is a problem. If you look at the logs, the following error is written

```
Feb 01 14:33:54 mysql-server mysqld_exporter[1603558]: ts=2024-02-01T10:33:54.337Z caller=exporter.go:152 level=error msg="Error pinging mysqld" err="Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysqld_exporter'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)"
Feb 01 14:34:09 mysql-server mysqld_exporter[1603558]: ts=2024-02-01T10:34:09.337Z caller=exporter.go:152 level=error msg="Error pinging mysqld" err="Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysqld_exporter'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)"
```

The user 'mysqld_exporter'@'127.0.0.1' exists and I can connect to mysql with it. Additionally, 'mysqld_exporter'@'localhost' was created. But nothing helps.

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

mysqld_exporter, version 0.15.1 (branch: HEAD, revision: cc349684494b5038ec5a52233bdca9eb9291e6f2)
  build user:       root@5c3174d21e8b
  build date:       20231212-07:54:18
  go version:       go1.21.5
  platform:         linux/arm64
  tags:             unknown
```